# Error: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a huge problem at the moment in my Unity project. I'm trying to add a certain number of elements to a SortedList, but when I start the game I get this error:

> error: "InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2[TrisCoordinates,System.Boolean].PutImpl
>   (.TrisCoordinates key, Boolean value, Boolean overwrite)
>   System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2[TrisCoordinates,System.Boolean].Add
>   (.TrisCoordinates key, Boolean value)"

Here is the code:

```
void AddCoords() {
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (280.62f, 2.217f, 144.84f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (280.65f, 0.9891f, 126.84f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (285.42f, 0.9891f, 129.49f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (281.64f, 2.9645f, 125.05f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (263.00f, 2.2f, 103.27f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (243.29f, 0.9891f, 101.96f), false); 
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (243.10f, 0.9891f, 99.587f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (233.20f, 1.018f, 93.414f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (249.77f, 0.9891f, 112.95f), false); 
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (247.87f, 0.9891f, 113.00f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (242.59f, 0.9891f, 112.92f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (240.59f, 0.9891f, 112.99f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (236.85f, 0.9891f, 112.99f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (234.79f, 0.9891f, 112.98f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (248.88f, 0.9891f, 126.71f), false); 
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (231.15f, 1.0182f, 148.53f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (270.95f, 7.95f, 137.46f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (278.60f, 7.95f, 137.60f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (281.85f, 7.9292f, 137.60f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (270.58f, 7.95f, 135.05f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (264.75f, 9.8372f, 118.75f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (256.27f, 7.93f, 103.37f), false); 
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (205.63f, 1.037f, 407.70f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (209.02f, 1.037f, 407.70f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (216.61f, 1.037f, 407.70f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (219.56f, 1.037f, 407.70f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (226.32f, 1.037f, 403.22f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (226.03f, 1.037f, 401.04f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (225.98f, 1.037f, 394.01f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (225.97f, 1.037f, 392.41f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (202.00f, 1.037f, 392.56f), false);
    coords.Add (new TrisCoordinates (201.03f, 1.037f, 394.67f), false);
}
```

TrisCoordinates is a class so made:

```
public class TrisCoordinates {

    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;

    public TrisCoordinates(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public float GetX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float GetY() {
        return y;
    }

    public float GetZ() {
        return z;
    }

}
```

Any ideas about what causes it?

Comment: "coords" is  SortedList, so made: 
SortedList<TrisCoordinates, bool> coords = new SortedList<TrisCoordinates, bool>();

Comment: there is a problem with adding abstract object in sorted list you should implement IComparable interface for your TrisCordinates class https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42a4c407-7115-4885-964e-1705f1b624db/problem-with-sortedlist?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: What do you mean with "abstract objects"? The first element is added without any problem to the SortedList, but just that one because from the second one I get that error.

Comment: abstract means object of a class, you not get error when adding string type

Comment: when you add first object then your list is empty that's why it added without any problem but when next object inserted then it will compare with first object and CompareTo method for that object is not available this is the problem

Comment: abstract does not mean object of a class, anyways, Virendra is correct. IComparable needs to be implemented.

Comment: yes Oguz Ozgul you are right i read about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should implement IComparable if you want to use the class as key for a SortedList, because to be able to sort, the sorted list should be able to compare two TrisCoordinates instances.

The below is a dummy comparison, but it should at least cause no exceptions in your code.

```
public class TrisCoordinates : IComparable<TrisCoordinates>
{

    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;

    public TrisCoordinates(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public float GetX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public float GetY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public float GetZ()
    {
        return z;
    }

    public int CompareTo(TrisCoordinates other)
    {
        return (x + y + z).CompareTo(other.x + other.y + other.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, now it works!! Thanks also to all the others who answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

You use a sortedlist the program should be able to sort your list, which, as your class doesn't implement the IComparable, is impossible. You just need to inherits from it: `public class TrisCoordinates : IComparable<TrisCoordinates>` and implement the `public int CompareTo(TrisCoordinates otherCoordinates)` to make it works:

```
public class TrisCoordinates : IComparable<TrisCoordinates>
{
    public float X { get; private set; }
    public float Y { get; private set; }
    public float Z { get; private set; }

    public TrisCoordinates(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
    public int CompareTo(TrisCoordinates otherCoordinates)
    {
        if (X > otherCoordinates.X)
            return 1;
        if (X < otherCoordinates.X)
            return -1;
        if (Y > otherCoordinates.Y)
            return 1;
        if (Y < otherCoordinates.Y)
            return -1;
        if (Z > otherCoordinates.Z)
            return 1;
        if (Z < otherCoordinates.Z)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```